# WPF place container on fixed position

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to place a container (with any custom content e.g. a ListView, ...) on a fixed position. The container should appear, when pressing a button. Take a look on this image:

[image: img]

**Press Me** and **Click Me** are buttons. If **Click Me** was clicked, the red container above should appear. Same with **Press Me**.

**My question**: how can I realise something like that? The red container should appear over all other controls (z-index). Is a `Canvas` the best choice? What's about the size of this container?

This question is really abstract. I don't want any solution, just some ideas about the container I should use and how it should be placed.

---

A question by the way.

Should I create the red containers in XAML and only change the state of `visiblity`? Or should I create the red containers in C#? In terms of performance.

---

Maybe some keywords to search are enough. Because I have no idea how to call this.

Comment: `In terms of performance` - I don't think you'll notice much of a difference either way you do it.

Comment: @VisualVincent thanks for the comment. Can you give me any advise how I can positioning it?

Comment: Sorry, WPF isn't really my strongest side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site is more about giving answers than adding to a discussion based on opinion. So in the spirit of things, and because it is far easier to answer this question with an example, here is how I would go about it.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Border x:Name="Container1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120" Height="100"
          Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="Hidden" />
  <Border x:Name="Container2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120" Height="100"
          Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="Hidden" />

  <Button x:Name="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Height="30"
          Grid.Row="2" Content="Press Me" Click="Button1_Click" />
  <Button x:Name="Button2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Height="30"
          Grid.Row="2" Content="Click Me" Click="Button2_Click" />
</Grid>
```

And for the code behind, I would do something like this:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isVisible = Container1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible;
    Container1.Visibility = isVisible ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isVisible = Container2.Visibility == Visibility.Visible;
    Container1.Visibility = isVisible ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
}
```

**1. How can I realise something like that? The red container should appear over all other controls (z-index).**

This is straight forward, putting the `<Grid>` element from my example above at the bottom of your XAML would make it sit on top of every other control, as elements are placed by default on the z-index based on their cascading order in XAML.

**2. Is a Canvas the best choice?**

Unless your top level container (Window, Page, UserControl) is of fixed width and height, I would recommend sticking with containers that deal better with the users ability to resize it. If you used a Canvas and the user was able to change the size of the top level container, you would have to manually re-position the buttons and border elements every time the top level container was resized to maintain position.

**3. What's about the size of this container?**

That is completely down to how big you wish to make your layout, in the example I have put sizes on the elements which would display correctly in a minimum container size of 340 x 340 pixels.

**4. Should I create the red containers in XAML and only change the state of visiblity? Or should I create the red containers in C#? In terms of performance.**

Placing the "container" elements in your XAML is your best bet, but being honest you would not notice a difference in speed. The only advantage to placing them in XAML is that it is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The idea to place the `grid` over all other elements is really nice. I wasn't thinking about this.